# Improving bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, nmap

I need to improve this script:

```
nmap -PN -p 9292 -sN 192.68.12.14 | grep "open"
```

I need to check connectivity to ip `192.168.15.24` on port `9292`.

If the port is open, then print "port 9292 is open"

If the port is closed, then print "port 9292 is closed"

The result will be taken from **icinga** to do a check.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from @DopeGhoti's correct answer using netcat, your script could be improved by changing some of your Nmap options and adding a few.

- `-sN` means "TCP NULL scan," which is a very unusual raw-socket scan mode requiring root privileges. It also has the odd property of only labeling ports as "closed" or "unfiltered" but never "open." You probably want a normal TCP Connect scan instead, using the `-sT` option.
- Nmap will attempt to do a reverse name lookup (`PTR`) by default. Avoid this unnecessary delay with the `-n` option.
- Using Nmap's normal screen output in a script is not recommended, even for something as simple as this, because it is subject to change between versions. For a stable, machine-parsable output format, use [grepable (`-oG`)](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) or [XML (`-oX`)](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html).
- `-PN` is an old [(deprecated in 2010)](https://nmap.org/changelog.html#5.30BETA1) spelling of `-Pn`. It skips the host discovery phase, so probably a good idea for your script.

Example with all of these changes:

```
nmap -n -Pn -sT -p 9292 -oG - | grep '/open/'
```

Answer (score 2):

This requires the `netcat` package:

```
if nc -z 192.68.12.14 9292; then
    echo "Port is open"
else
    echo "Port is closed"
fi
```

`nc -z` will attempt to make a connection to the specified host and port; it returns a `0` exit code upon success, and a nonzero code otherwise.  It does not actually output anything to the terminal.  To get your desired output, I use an `if` statement to test the results of the connection test, and `echo` the appropriate result to the terminal.

Comment: thanks but the command nc -z 192.168.12.14 9292 output is empty...

Comment: Thus the `if` and `echo` statements.  `nc` does not output anything; it returns an exit code apropos of the results of the connection attempt.

Comment: sh check_connection.sh 




Port is open